# Java applet - Does not initialize and has NullPointerException errors

Tags: java, applet

I gathered class files from a website for a java applet. I decompiled the files to get java files. I placed them in Eclipse. When I "**run as applet**" it doesn't initialize and I get this **error**:

> java.lang.NullPointerException at
>   sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(Unknown Source) at
>   sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(Unknown Source) at
>   java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Unknown Source) at
>   java.lang.Double.valueOf(Unknown Source) at
>   SampleDistApplet.start(SampleDistApplet.java:44) at
>   sun.applet.AppletPanel.run(Unknown Source) at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Can anyone help me with this issue?

Comment: First, without some code it's hard to help. Second you should at least try and debug that yourself. With just copy and paste you're not going to learn anything.

Comment: I have 15 class files. How can I share all of them on here? Also I have tried to debug myself and do not know much about applets.

Comment: What are you trying to do here?  Are you sure that scraping and decompiling the applet is permitted by the website's terms and conditions?  Remember that copyright laws apply to this kind of thing.

Comment: I don't need a lecture. I got this from an educational website.

Comment: *"I have 15 class files. How can I share all of them on here? Also I have tried to debug myself and do not know much about applets"* - I think we probably can't help you then.  (And I'm not sure we should be either ...)

Comment: *"I don't need a lecture."*.  Actually, you probably DO *need* a lecture.  You just don't *want* one.  *"I got this from an educational website."* - That is not relevant.  Copyright law makes no distinction between educational websites and other websites.  And besides, it is one thing to do something illegal, and another thing again to ask other people to help you.  Have you considered that?

Comment: How can I get an applet to work with an initialization error and null error? That is all I need answers on.

Comment: If it is educational, then there's surely some source code. Besides that debugging isn't restricted to applets. Have a look at the error message: there's at least one hint where to start looking. And IIRC you can run applets in debug mode in Eclipse or other IDEs.

Comment: When I run the applet, it says failed to initialize. I changed the init() function to run() and then it changes to "applet started" and doesn't display the null errors. However, the screen is blank.

Comment: Also I added a try, catch which fixed errors but still get a blank screen. However it works in browser so I don't get what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

Copy and paste of applet class files do'nt work properly after decompiling in my view. Instead you create own applet files then run it. Then you also get some practice about applet applications.

Comment: Is there any decompiler that is accurate? I used Procyon Decompiler.

Comment: NullPointerException is run-time error. If there was problem with decompilation, there would be a compile time error and compilation will not be possible.

Comment: Ah okay. I added a try, catch so that it would ignore the null exception. After I did this, the applet says "applet started" but is blank.